# regular expression for validation that only take double amount value should not take word, -ve value etc. in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

regular expression that only take double amount value should not take word, -ve value in javascript

```
$('document').ready(function() {
        $(".btn").click(function() {
            var amount = $('#amountId').val();

            if (amount <= 0) {
                alert("Please insert a valid Amount! ");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I tried this but I want more validation as I mentioned above only double amount should be there nothing else than double amount

Comment: Please post examples of valid and invalid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)?

From MDN:

> The following examples all return 3.14

```
parseFloat("3.14");
parseFloat("314e-2");
parseFloat("0.0314E+2");
parseFloat("3.14more non-digit characters");
```

Comment: no, sorry you didn't get what I meant to say I just want a regex in javascript which can take only double value as input ex. 10.00, 1234.00, 123456.1234, etc. only double values will be allowed not abcd ,-1.00 not allowed even 0.0 will not be allowed

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in several steps, look for invalid characters, then strip the whitespace, then check for a valid integer, then parse it and check the value.

However if you want to try in one regex, you might try something like this:

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?([eE][-+][0-9]*)?$/
```

You need to deal with the whitespace first (`trim` the input string) if whitespace is to be ignored. You'll also need to filter out 0 if that's not allowed.

The function below does some of this and returns an object with the parsed number (using `parseFloat` as suggested by **epoch**) and an indication if it is valid. You should be able to put this into your code and tweak it to do what you want:

```
function processInput(s) {
    var pattern = /^[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?([eE][-+][0-9]*)?$/
    var answer = { result: 0, isValid: false };

    // remove whitespace from start and end 
    s = s.trim();
    if (s.length > 0) { 
        answer.isValid = pattern.test(s);
        if (answer.isValid) { 
            answer.result = parseFloat(s);
        }
        // Might need a special test for 0 here
    }
    return answer;
}
```

I've probably missed a specific case or two, but I tested a bunch of likely things, output:

```
'3' ->  { result: 3, isValid: true }
'.289213123' ->     { result: 0.289213123, isValid: true }
'0.2' ->    { result: 0.2, isValid: true }
'3.14' ->   { result: 3.14, isValid: true }
'3.14.14' ->    { result: 0, isValid: false }
'-3.14' ->  { result: 0, isValid: false }
'314e-2' ->     { result: 3.14, isValid: true }
'0.0314E+2' ->  { result: 3.14, isValid: true }
'3.14more non-digit characters' ->  { result: 0, isValid: false }
'3.' ->     { result: 3, isValid: true }
'' ->   { result: 0, isValid: false }
```

Note the valid negative number returns false because you said negatives are not allowed in your input. So this isn't a general 'isNumeric' it's more tailored for this case. You could also drop the stuff to match the exponent syntax if you want.